# How to toggle Angularjs ng-show without $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

As you might have read on the [Angularjs FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#faq_common-pitfalls_-exists,-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil) the use of `$rootScope` is not encouraged. Therefore, a service is more appropriate for storing data that would be shared later on between controllers.. But I couldn't make the `ng-show` directive work without the use of `$rootScope`.

Here's what i'm doing;

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
    <div ng-show="showSettings"></div>
    <aside  ng-show="showSettings" >
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <button ng-click="closeSettings()">Ok</button>
    </aside>
</div>
```

**app.js**
(I bootstrap the app since I'm developing for cordova.. code truncated)

```
var app = angular.module('tibibt', ['tibibt.controllers', 'tibibt.filters', 'tibibt.services']);
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['tibibt']);
});
```

**services.js**

```
/* Create an application module that holds all services */
var tibibtServicess = angular.module('tibibt.services', []);

/* Global service */
tibibtServicess.service('globalService', function () {
    this.Data = {
        showSettings: 'false'
    };
    this.getAll = function () {
        return this.Data;
    };
    this.setSettings = function (val) {
        this.Data.showSettings = val;
    };
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
/* Create an application module that holds all controllers */
var tibibtControllers = angular.module('tibibt.controllers', []);

tibibtControllers.controller('GlobalCtrl', function ($scope, globalService) {

// Get initial value
$scope.showSettings = globalService.getAll().showSettings;
console.log('Settings initially set to -> ' + globalService.getAll().showSettings);

// Open settings menu
$scope.openSettings = function () {
    globalService.setSettings('true');
    console.log('Settings set to -> ' + globalService.getAll().showSettings);
};

// Close settings menu
$scope.closeSettings = function () {
    globalService.setSettings('false');
    console.log('Settings set to -> ' + globalService.getAll().showSettings);
};
});
```

The console shows the changes but the `ng-show` doesn't bind/update to this changes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.Data = globalService.getAll();
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
    <div ng-show="Data.showSettings"></div>
    <aside  ng-show="Data.showSettings" >
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <button ng-click="closeSettings()">Ok</button>
    </aside>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VvDgD/)

**Explanation**:

This line `$scope.showSettings = globalService.getAll().showSettings;`  assign data **by value** => the value of showSettings is copied to `$scope.showSettings` => they are 2 separate blocks of memory. When you change the `globalService.Data.showSettings`, `$scope.showSettings` is not updated because it's another block of memory.

Changing to `$scope.Data = globalService.getAll();` assign data ***by reference*** => they point to the same block of memory.

Comment: @numediaweb: It should be `$scope.Data = globalService.getAll();`. I updated my answer again. Typing too fast made a mistake.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the explanation ;) by the way Is this (data by ref/val) related only to/mentioned in the Angularjs docs, or this is standard javascript "rules" or behaviours?

Comment: @numediaweb: it's standard javascript. In fact, ref/val concepts are general concepts. These concepts also exist in some server frameworks like c#.net

Answer (score 5):

this is only an assignment thats evaluated once:

```
$scope.showSettings = globalService.getAll().showSettings;
```

so the value will never change.

there are at least to possible solutions:

1. assign the service to the scope: $scope.settings = globalService. Now you may access the service in your view:

   ```
   ng-show="settings.getAll().showSettings"
   ```
2. or register a watch by yourself:

   ```
    $scope.showSettings = false;
    $scope.$watch(globalService.getAll().showSettings, function(newValue){
       $scope.showSettings = newValue;
    });
   ```

Comment: +1 :) Thanks for the answer. I ahd to choose the other answer since Khanh TO put lot of effort and demo.. but your answer is also correct ;)